# Send string via Bluetooth from Raspberry Pi to Arduino C

Tags: c, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to send a string via bluetooth from a Raspberry Pi to an Arduino connected to an HC-05 bluetooth chip via C code.

I have successfully received data from the Arduino on the PI using an rfcomm socket that get's initialised on the PI written to by the Arduino via the bluetooth dongle and then read by the PI.

Is there a similar method where by I can initialise and write data to the bluetooth dongle to be sent to the Arduino.

Comment: You are using a bluetooth dongle on the pi to receive data from an arduino with an hc-05 over bluetooth?

Comment: I was, this project was a few years ago now, pretty sure I got it working in the end.